# is there any site with historical radiotelescope data about observations 21 cm line Hydrogen (1.42 GHz)?

Tags: observational-astronomy, radio-astronomy, history, radio-telescope, resource-request

I am looking for an open source that contain **historical raw data** or (meta)data about historical observations of the 21 cm line hydrogen made via radio telescopes.

Comment: Your [tag:resource-request] question is certainly on-topic here. If you have no luck with answers here after a while (but I think you will) you could then consider having this migrated to [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) (HSM SE). But that site is more about the history while you are really asking for sources for historical data or records thereof.

Answer (score 1):

The whole SETI project started by making observations on this frequency, using the Big Ear telescope.

My recommendation is go to the wikipedia page about the [Wow! Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wow!_signal) and follow the links from there.

If I find anything that may be more specifically useful, I will add it here:

[Breakthrough Listen Search for the WOW! Signal](https://seti.berkeley.edu/wow/).
*This article includes links to [raw data](https://bldata.berkeley.edu/6EQUJ5/).*

[The Breakthrough Listen Search for Intelligent Life: Public Data, Formats, Reduction and Archiving](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07391)
Matthew Lebofsky, et al.

*Not sure how much of this is on hydrogen line.*